# Byte of python(Inheritance)

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I'm a little stuck on this chapter of the book. I've written everything down verbatim(as far as I can see). and I'm getting an error that, "SchoolMember" is not defined.

```
class SchoolMember:
    '''Represents any school member.'''
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('(Initialized SchoolMember:{})'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        '''Tell my details.'''
        print('Name:"{}" Age:"{}"'.format(self.name, self.age), end=" ")

class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    '''Represents a teacher.'''
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.salary = salary
        print('(Initialzed Teacher: {}'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        SchoolMemeber.tell(self)
        print('Salary: "{:d}"'.format(self, salary))

class Student(SchoolMemeber):
    '''Represents a student.'''
    def __init__(self, name, age, marks):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.marks = marks
        print('(Initialized Student: {})'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print('Marks: {:d}'.format(self.marks))

t = Teacher('Mrs. Shrividya', 40, 30000)
s = Student('Bruce'< 25, 75)

# prints a blank line
print()

members = [t, s]
for member in members:
    # Works for bith Teachers and Students
    member.tell()
```

Comment: Spellcheck will solve this...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In `tell()` you wrote `SchoolMemeber` instead of `SchoolMember`

Comment: Flag to close for simple typos